# Find only increasing values from one line to the next

Tags: python, perl, bash, sed, awk

I would like to print out values (or identify lines) that do *not* increase from one line to the next.

Perl, Awk/Sed, bash, or python...any will do.

```
1001<br>
1002<br>
1003<br>
1004<br>
1005<br>
1006<br>
1007<br>
1004<br>
1008<br>
1009<br>
```

This should locate from "1007" to the next line "1004" and identify one line or the other or both.

Comment: What have you tried? You must demonstrate that you have actually tried to solve your problem yourself.

Answer (score 3):

This can be a way:

```
awk 'prev>=$1 {print $0, "<----"; a[$1]=NR; next} prev=$1;
    END{print "** repeated lines **";
        for (i in a) print "line "a[i]" value",i; printf "\n"}' file
```

#### Test

```
$ awk 'prev>=$1 {print $0, "<----"; a[$1]=NR; next} prev=$1; END{print "** repeated lines **"; for (i in a) print "line "a[i]" value",i; printf "\n"}' a
1001
1002
1003
1004
1005
1006
1007
1004 <----
1008
1009
** repeated lines **
line 8 value 1004
```

With other input:

```
$ cat a
1006
1007
1004
1008
1009
133
1333
123
$ awk 'prev>=$1 {print $0, "<----"; a[$1]=NR; next} prev=$1; END{print "** repeated lines **"; for (i in a) print "line "a[i]" value",i; printf "\n"}' a
1006
1007
1004 <----
1008
1009
133 <----
1333
123 <----
** repeated lines **
line 8 value 123
line 6 value 133
line 3 value 1004
```

Comment: +1 for the pointer `<---` but I think to print the line number would be better. think about if the file had 3000 lines

Comment: Good idea, @Kent, just updated accordingly. I remember we both answered something similar in the past, but couldn't find it...

Comment: okay, then I am posting another answer to this question too :)

Answer (score 3):

if you have `sort`, it can give all you need. with the option `-c` check man page.

for example, with your data:

```
kent$  echo "1001
1002
1003
1004
1005
1006
1007
1004
1008
1009"|sort -c
sort: -:8: disorder: 1004
```

so you got line number and that line.

Comment: This wouldn't catch that 1007->1007 doesn't increase.

Answer (score 2):

Perl solution:

```
perl -ne 'print $previous if $_ < $previous; $previous = $_' input.txt
```

Just remember the previous line, compare, print if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Python based solution using the data from @fedorqui's solution:

```
>>> from itertools import tee, izip
with open('abc1') as f:
    t1, t2 = tee(f)
    next(t2)
    for line1, line2 in izip(t1, t2):
        if int(line1) > int(line2):
            print line1, line2
...             
1007
1004

1009
133

1333
123
```